# Does Dynamic Linq support BindingList<T>?

Tags: .net-4.0, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

**Question**

I'm trying to use the [Dynamic Linq Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) from Microsoft with `BindingList<T>` objects.  But it looks like the Dynamic Linq will only work with `IQueryable`.  What's the deal here, why doesn't `BindingList<T>` implement `IQueryable`.  And is there a way around this?

---

**Background Detail:**  I have many data sets that I need to dynamically filter at run time.  Here is an example:

```
BindingList<MyObject> list = new BindingList<MyObject>();
MyObject selectedObj = list.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "Master P")

// then later ...
MyObject selectedObj = list.FirstOrDefault(o => o.City == "Boston")
```

I am trying to make these queries dynamic, so the user can choose from all properties of `MyObject` to use in the query.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Extension method on BindingList; AsQueryable(). So you can use

```
list.AsQueryable();
```

But if you want to search on all criteria could you create a search that uses an instance of MyObject as the search criteria and then generated a result set based on the Criteria in the object using standard link.

For example:

```
public List<MyObject> Search(MyObject SearchCriteria)
    {
        BindingList<MyObject> list = new BindingList<MyObject>();
        list.Add(new MyObject("Test", "Boston"));
        list.Add(new MyObject("Test2", "Atlanta"));

        IEnumerable<MyObject> results = list.AsEnumerable();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchCriteria.Name))
            results = results.Where(l => l.Name.Contains(SearchCriteria.Name));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchCriteria.City))
            results = results.Where(l => l.City.Contains(SearchCriteria.City));
        return results.ToList();

    }
```

So in the following, Results1 will have 2 results and Results 2 will have only 1.

```
List<MyObject> results1 = Search(new MyObject("Test", ""));
List<MyObject> results2 = Search(new MyObject("Test", "Boston"));
```

I used a simple structure for MyObject as an example in this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(string name, string city)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.City = city;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```